# Builder pattern set method in swift

Tags: ios, swift, builder

I am just shifted from Android base to ios, looking for builder pattern get and set method in swift unable to find anything like it. Found following only

```
var ptype : String? {
    get{
        return self.ptype
    }set (ptype) {
        self.ptype = ptype
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use that code. It will cause infinite recursion. That whole thing should simply be `var pType: String?`.

Comment: Is this what you want https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/using-the-builder-pattern-in-swift.

Comment: What do you mean with Builder pattern? The code you have shared is simply only for assigning a property.

Comment: Set should return object itself

Comment: Property assignments never return a value. You would have to implement your setters as functions (rather than property setters). But I wouldn't even bother, unless there's lots of values, just use multiple assignment statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following tip looks like what you wanted https://github.com/vincent-pradeilles/swift-tips#implementing-the-builder-pattern-with-keypaths. I'll copy code here for quick looking.

```
protocol With {}

extension With where Self: AnyObject {
    @discardableResult
    func with<T>(_ property: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Self, T>, setTo value: T) -> Self {
        self[keyPath: property] = value
        return self
    }
}

extension UIView: With {}

let view = UIView()

let label = UILabel()
    .with(\.textColor, setTo: .red)
    .with(\.text, setTo: "Foo")
    .with(\.textAlignment, setTo: .right)
    .with(\.layer.cornerRadius, setTo: 5)

view.addSubview(label)
```

Answer (score 5):

After using so many libraries written in Swift, I have rarely seen people use the builder pattern in Swift.

I think the Builder Pattern's main advantages can already be achieved with Swift's other language features. You can totally create a constructor where all the parameters are optional, and you almost just recreated the builder pattern in Swift:

```
class Foo {
    let a: Int
    let b: String
    let c: Bool

    init(a: Int = 0, b: String = "", c: Bool = false) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    }
}
```

You can create a `Foo` like this:

```
// You can omit any of the arguments, just like the builder pattern
Foo(
    a: 123
    b: "Hello World"
    c: true
)
```

I would argue that's an even cleaner version of something like this in Java:

```
new FooBuilder()
    .setA(123)
    .setB("Hello World")
    .setC(true)
    .build()
```

But if you insist, here is some really verbose Swift that implements the Builder pattern:

```
class Foo {
    private(set) var a: Int = 0
    private(set) var b: String = ""
    private(set) var c: Bool = false

    init(a: Int = 0, b: String = "", c: Bool = false) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    }

    class Builder {
        private var innerFoo = Foo()

        @discardableResult
        func withA(_ a: Int) -> Builder {
            innerFoo.a = a
            return self
        }

        @discardableResult
        func withB(_ b: String) -> Builder {
            innerFoo.b = b
            return self
        }

        @discardableResult
        func withC(_ c: Bool) -> Builder {
            innerFoo.c = c
            return self
        }

        func build() -> Foo {
            return innerFoo
        }
    }
}
```